# Should I expect Sorbet to perform platform-dependently?

Tags: ruby, sorbet

I've run into some trouble when changing the image I've been using for my CI process on CircleCI. I changed the image when I upgraded my version of Ruby.

`bundle exec srb tc` is running fine locally however it's flipping out with thousands of errors in CircleCI. I've wiped all of my local gems and reinstalled to match production but it doesn't make any difference to the errors.

The only thing I can tell that is different between the two environments is that my local environment is OSX and the remote one is linux (as are the production servers).

**Local**

```sh
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.7.5p203 (2021-11-24 revision f69aeb8314) [x86_64-darwin20]
```

**Circle CI**

```sh
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.7.5p203 (2021-11-24 revision f69aeb8314) [x86_64-linux]
```

Is that enough to account for all of the errors in Sorbet? And if so, how would I even go about fixing them given that I am running on Mac locally?

**This wasn't a problem before**

It's possible that this isn't the trigger. However builds were working in a prior environment on CircleCI using a different Ruby version, they just aren't now.

Comment: You have to inject the relevant platforms into your Gemfile.lock.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is that it was not the platform that was affecting things, it was where the gem had been installed. I'm going to leave the question up on SO though just as a testament to the null result.

The issue triggering the errors turned out to be changing where the gem is installed - [SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71515275/why-does-sorbet-throw-thousands-of-errors-when-you-change-the-gem-installation-l)